# Search listview using datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, datagridview

I have created a datagridview and want to get data from listview control using searching in datagridview textbox in C# I am trying the following event but this event have not help.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) // datagridview first cell enter event
        {
            listViewFill();//fill listview bind method 
            listView1.Show();//showing listview    
            listView1.Select();// Select the search item
        }
    }
```

So please help me for fill datagridview from listview

Comment: I don't understand what you want to accomplish. So you're entering a cell in a `DataGridView`. What exactly do you want to happen? Please specify some more details. What do the methods above do? What does not work in the above code?

Comment: i have created a datagridview control and want to add multiple rows in this from listview control which is bind from database with listviewFill(); method given above.so when I press any key in datagridview 1st cell then listview control should be show and I will be to enter required data in datagridview 1st cell and can be select matched data from listview control and send selected listview row to datagridview cell.What I do which fill my requirement